# Failed to install the requested application Flutter Xcode error m1 mac

Tags: ios, flutter

Failed to install the requested application
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 22
Failure Reason: The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Recovery Suggestion: Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.

I've tried all the avialable things to do, but nothing helps me. Also ive been fighting with bunch of other problems with running app. Now it builds but still failed to install
macOS Version 12.2
Xcode 13.2.1